How to log and pow python xarrays?
I'm trying to calculate temperature and pressure at lifting condensation level in Python. My formulas which don't work are:
import xarray as xr
import constants as const #just keeping all my constants in one place

def opengrib(filename, **kwargs):
    if 'filter' in kwargs:
        ds = xr.open_dataset(f'{const.gribdir}/{filename}', engine='cfgrib', filter_by_keys=kwargs['filter'])
    else:
        ds = xr.open_dataset(f'{const.gribdir}/{filename}', engine='cfgrib')
    ds = adjust_longitude(ds)
    ds = ds.sel(latitude=slice(max_lat,min_lat), longitude=slice(min_lon,max_lon))
    return ds

# That grib file is 1.6GB. I have no way of providing it, unfortunately
ds2m = opengrib('levels.grib2', filter={'typeOfLevel': 'heightAboveGround','cfVarName': ['t2m','r2']})
t2m = ds2m.metpy.parse_cf('t2m') - 273.16
rh2m = ds2m.metpy.parse_cf('r2')
dp2m=t2m-((14.55+0.114*t2m)*(1-0.01*rh2m)+pow((2.5+0.007*t2m)*(1-0.01*rh2m),3)+(15.9+0.117*t2m)*pow((1-0.01*rh2m),14))


tlcl = (((1/(1/((dp2m+273.16)-56)+log((t2m/(dp2m+273.16)))/800))+56)-273.16)
plcl = ( pressfc * pow( ((tlcl+273.16)/t2m),(7/2) ))/100

dp2m, t2m and pressfc are all xarray.DataArray and I would like to get a DataArray as a result. The problem seems to be the log and pow invocations. How do I do this correctly in Python?

Edit: I tried this with math.log and np.log
Edit2: add imports and missing variables


Hi. Please [edit] your post to add in the import lines you used. Was it from math import log or from numpy import log or from cmath import log or something else?

Can you try with numpy.log and replacing pow(..., (7/2)) with (...)**(7/2)?

Also, right now if we try executing your code we get a bunch of errors because we don't have the definition of dp2m and t2m and log. When trying to get answers on StackOverflow, I strongly suggest posting code as a [mre]. In particular, xarray.DataArray is not a type from the python standard library, which means you got it by importing a library, and since you didn't include the import in the code you shown us, we have to guess which one in order to answer your question.

Ah, sorry. That's quite a rabbit hole. I'll try to complete it

With np.log I get /home/sgofferj/Dev/saakeskus.fi/python-render/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xarray/core/computation.py:821: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log   result_data = func(*input_data) and the resulting array has a lot of nan fields

So it seems your problem is just the NaN values?

Or is it that the array you call log on has negative values?

It would be much much simpler to help you if you could reproduce the problem with a truly minimum and reproducible example, something as simple as import numpy as np; x = np.array([12, 3, 4]); y = np.log(x) cause right now I'm still just guessing, since I don't know what your arrays are (the code you added doesn't help, since it relies on reading values from a file)

Note how import numpy as np; x = np.array([12, 3, 4]); y = np.log(x) can be executed without an error but import numpy as np; x = np.array([12, -3, 4]); y = np.log(x) results in a RuntimeWarning. This is because logarithm expects positive numbers.

Yes, there are negative values in the array! So numpy log doesn't like negative values... Then I have to find out while Grads doesn't complain...
I'm sorry, I'm a python beginner coming from a C background. I barely understand the datatypes and especially DataArrays are too complex for my understanding yet. It also doesn't really help that in Python literally everything has a different name and I'm no English native speaker...

The problem was my stupidity. I copied the formulas from my Grads script and didn't pay attention to the variables. In Grads, t2m is in Kelvin, not Celsius. After adding 273.16 to all occurrences of t2m in the python script, it works as expected. Apologies for wasting your time!

No apology needed. Glad you found the root of the issue!

The problem was my stupidity. I copied the formulas from my Grads script and didn't pay attention to the variables. In Grads, t2m is in Kelvin, not Celsius. After adding 273.16 to all occurrences of t2m in the python script, it works as expected. Apologies for wasting your time!
